# vbscript call isql script

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, crystal-reports

I have a current vbscript that runs a simple sql statement and passes this to a crystal report to run against a sybase database - like below

```
SybaseRecordSet.Open "SELECT * FROM v2Region where code IN ('BTN', 'MAN', 'IRE', 'DUB')", SybaseConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
```

I would like to run a more complex sql statement and have tried various ways to add this into the sql script without success

Is there a way for the command below to open an external sql txt file into a variable and then open like below

> Function do_something
>
> Dim fso
>
> Set file = fso.OpenTextFile("D:\ideal v2.5\Amalgamated_Overdue_Report.sql", 1)
>
> sql_content = file.ReadAll
>
> SybaseRecordSet.Open sql_content, SybaseConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic

currently this is giving
Error - Object required: 'fso'
code - 800A01A8

Comment: `Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")` missing?

Comment: thanks - big DOH! to me as to why I missed that.